# IBM Worklight - How to replace the default app icon for iPhone?

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm confused by ALL the various icon files in the resources folder.

I just want to replace the one for the iPhone main screen.
Any idea which that is?  And is there any table that describes what each icon is for and size requirements etc?

Comment: I know SO doesnt like it but: google iphone icon sizes OR look at the dupes here

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconMatrix.html